# RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo after adding a few imageButtons

Tags: android, android-studio

My application works without a problem until I added few imagebuttons, (one had no problems)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jarek.stratcaller/com.example.jarek.stratcaller.ChooseMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
        at com.example.jarek.stratcaller.ChooseMapActivity.onCreate(ChooseMapActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.example.jarek.stratcaller.ChooseMapActivity.onCreate(ChooseMapActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4000012 byte allocation with 1511784 free bytes and 1476KB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:758)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:175)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1095)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1017)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2418)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:634)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.example.jarek.stratcaller.ChooseMapActivity.onCreate(ChooseMapActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

This is my ChooseMapActivity class:

```
package com.example.jarek.stratcaller;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ChooseMapActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_map);

        /* TODO: Commentary to map settings */
        Button Dust2_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dust2_button);
        Dust2_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ChooseMapActivity.this, ChooseSideActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#6c6976"
tools:context=".ChooseMapActivity">

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/dust2_button"
            android:background="@drawable/dust2_custom_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/cache_button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dust2_button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dust2_button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dust2_button"
            android:background="@drawable/cache_custom_button"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/nuke_button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dust2_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dust2_button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dust2_button"
            android:background="@drawable/nuke_custom_button"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/mirage_button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nuke_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nuke_button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nuke_button"
            android:background="@drawable/mirage_custom_button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/overpass_button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mirage_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nuke_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nuke_button"
        android:background="@drawable/overpass_custom_button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/inferno_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nuke_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nuke_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nuke_button"
        android:background="@drawable/inferno_custom_button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/cobblestone_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mirage_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mirage_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mirage_button"
        android:background="@drawable/cobblestone_custom_button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/train_button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cobblestone_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cobblestone_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cobblestone_button"
        android:background="@drawable/train_custom_button"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to find the solution but for me, my line:18 in ChooseMapActivity class is totally fine, any ideas?

Comment: You're getting `OutOfMemoryError` possibly because of a large bitmap, maybe with smaller images

Comment: That fixed a problem, thank you!

Comment: Hi @henorek, I posted my answer so you can marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appear in your logcat:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4000012 byte allocation with 1511784 free bytes and 1476KB until OOM
```

This is possibly because of a large bitmap, maybe with smaller images.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not valid, your first tag is closed twice. Remove this part:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">
```